# Find out whether a SQL table has entries without a "flagged" record

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a `MySQL` table of addresses with the following columns:

```
STATE, ZIPCODE, FLAG
```

There can be multiple rows for a given `state/zipcode` combination. I'd like to make sure that for every given `state/zipcode` combination, there is exactly one row having `FLAG = 'P'`.

I know how to check for multiple rows:

```
SELECT state, zipcode, flag, count(*) as numrecs
FROM addresses
WHERE flag = 'P'
group by state, zipcode
having numrecs > 1;
```

How do I check for zero entries - a `state/zipcode` combination with no rows whose `flag = 'P'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should give you the ones that violate your criterion:

```
SELECT STATE, ZIPCODE, SUM(FLAG_COUNTER)
FROM (SELECT *, IF(FLAG='P', 1, 0) AS FLAG_COUNTER FROM addresses) tableWithCounter
GROUP BY STATE, ZIPCODE
HAVING SUM(FLAG_COUNTER) != 1
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but I get "Every derived table must have its own alias".

Comment: is "MyTable" the alias? Where does the actual table name ("addresses") go?

Comment: @user3798040 MyTable is a placeholder for your actual table name, since I did not see it in original post. `tableWithCounter` is the alias for the derived table, doesn't matter what you use there.

Comment: Ah. Now it works...thanks! I think I needed to refresh the page in order to see "tableWithCounter".

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT state, zipcode, flag, count(*) as numrecs
FROM addresses
GROUP BY state, zipcode
HAVING coalesce(sum(flag = 'P'), 0) <> 1
```

or, if you prefer:

```
HAVING coalesce(sum(flag = 'P'), 0) = 0 or sum(flag = 'P') > 1
```

The `coalesce()` is needed just in case `flag` can be `NULL` and a given state/zipcode combination has only `NULL` flags.

Comment: Shouldnt it be sum(coalesce(.. ?

Comment: Thank you. I assume this is working - it's telling me 0 rows returned, which is what I hoped for :)

Comment: Deliberately create a condition where the constraint is violated, and test that it does get returned by this query! (For that matter, test my answer too! I think both should work so pick which is more readable to you. For very large data sets I would not be surprised if my answer is slower since it creates a temporary table, but perhaps not enough slower to be noticeable.)

Comment: O okay, I thought maybe SUM() would always return NULL if one of the values is NULL.

Comment: @popovitsj . . . `sum()` only returns `NULL` if *all* the values are `NULL`.  In this case, that could only happen if all the flags on the state/zip were `NULL`, which is what I tried to say in the comment.